# Yajisan-Kazusan: Diagonal Arrows

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Yajisan-Kazusan puzzle.

**Rules of Yajisan-Kazusan:**

> Several numbered arrows are given in the grid. Shade some cells so that:
>
> - no two shaded cells are adjacent
> - unshaded cells form a single, orthogonally connected group
> - all *unshaded* clues count the number of shaded cells in the direction their arrows point. (Shaded clues may be true or false; they provide no information.)
>
> Example ([from GMPuzzles](https://www.gmpuzzles.com/blog/2017/11/yajisan-kazusan-thomas-snyder/)):
>
> [image]

...However, this puzzle has *diagonal* arrows. And not only that, diagonal arrows positioned within the cells. Arrows that point to a *vertex* will only point to a single diagonal line of cells; arrows that point to an *edge* will alternate back and forth between two diagonal lines of cells.

For instance, the [0↗] clue in row 3 points to only two cells: the fourth cell in row 2, and the fifth cell in row 1. But the [1↘] clue in row 2 points to *five* cells: the third and second from the right of row 3, the last two of row 4, and the [4↙] clue in row 5.

[image]

Comment: Does adjacency now mean *diagonally* adjacent only?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry No, adjacency still means orthogonally adjacent only. Diagonally adjacent shaded cells are allowed; orthogonally adjacent cells are not allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provided I haven't made any mistakes, here is the solution

> [image]

Comment: Yep, that's correct!